# MCI load video file

Tags: visual-c++, media-player, mci

I'm trying to load then play a video file with mci in my visual c++ application but the mciSendString() method keeps failing and returning an error code. The error code is 259 meanings "MCIERR_UNRECOGNIZED_KEYWORD". The command and format looks good to me and when I debug through it the filename gets placed properly in the command string. Im not sure whats causing this.

```
bool Player::Load(String^ fileName)
{
DWORD dwReturn = 0;
CString myStr(fileName);
CString strCommand;
strCommand.Format(L"Open %s type avivideo alias AVIFile", myStr);

dwReturn = mciSendString(strCommand, NULL, 0, NULL);

if (dwReturn)
    return false; // An error has occurred while trying to open the video file

return true;
```

}

Comment: Why are you using MCI and not DirectShow or MediaFoundation?

Comment: Its the assignment requirement unfortunately. Were learning directshow next..

Comment: Can you dump the value of `strCommand` after the call to `CString::Format`?

Comment: open C:\Users\JC\Videos\Test.AVI type avivideo alias AVIFile 
When i debug it but it just seems to be 'o' when I print it

Comment: I think the problem is you're using wide-character strings whereas `mciSendString` expects `LPCTSTR` which might be defined as a 1-byte character string. Try removing the `L` prefix from your `"Open %s ty..."` string and see if that works.

Comment: It seems to need the L, I get this error after removing it
http://postimage.org/image/i0xeussx7/

Comment: When I hard code the command string into mciSendString() it returns 0 which is good and returns true. But only when I use "open Test.avi type avivideo alias AVIFiles" and put the file in my project directory.

Comment: I suggest using C++'s `basic_string` rather than MFC's `CString` then. If you're still having problems please post it as a new question.